# Spring--cannot convert javax.mail.session

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, jakarta-mail

I am creating a mail session inside of my servlet context and then using JNDI to inject it into my spring framework design. Here's how the context looks:

```
<Resource name="mail/session" auth="Container"
            type="javax.mail.Session"
            mail.smtp.from="noreply@xxxx.com"
            mail.smtp.user="noreply@xxxx.com"
            mail.smtp.auth="true"
            mail.smtp.starttls.enable="true"
/>
```

And where I'm bringing it in:

```
  <bean id="smtpSession" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/mail/session"/>
  </bean>
```

and where I'm injecting it into the spring java mail sender:

```
  <bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
      <property name="host" ref="smtpHost"/>
      <property name="password" ref="smtpPassword"/>
      <property name="port" ref="smtpPort"/>
      <property name="username" ref="smtpFrom"/>
      <property name="session" ref="smtpSession"/>
  </bean>
```

Now here's the message I'm getting:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [javax.
mail.Session] to required type [javax.mail.Session] for property 'session': no m
atching editors or conversion strategy found
        at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(Ty
peConverterDelegate.java:231)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrap
perImpl.java:447)
        ... 51 more
```

Uh, what???? Why is it trying to convert it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You most likely have two copies if `javax.mail.Session` on your classpath. One probably comes from the appserver's internal libraries, the other is likely packed in your app's `lib` directory. The two copies will clash when you try and use them like this.

Remove the one in your app's `lib` directory, and try again.

Comment: That is exactly what it was, but I didn't understand this would be a problem. Is it that the class loader separates the instances somehow and it's comparing the address in memory?

Comment: @Thom: Java treats two classes with the same name but loaded from different classloaders as incompatible. You can't cast from one to the other, even if their definitions are identical.

Comment: This solved my issue as well. I must say it was quite annoying, I was looking for a duplicate `mail.jar`, but after using a tool and searching for `javax.mail.Session` I noticed that Apache CXF depends on Apache Geronimo which has its own JavaMail implementation.

Comment: It was apache CXF for me too!

Comment: Can you please name the jar of Apache CXF? I am facing the same issue. Mail.jar and mailapi.jar both are in tomcat/lib only. I have removed from web-inf/lib but still i am facing this issue.

Answer (score 3):

This is a classloading issue. Usually this is because the class is both in a jar in your server ***and*** in your application. In this case, you probably want to remove it from your application. Do you have something like **mail.jar** in your WEB-INF/lib or EAR?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Mail.jar and mailapi.jar both are in tomcat/lib only. I have removed from web-inf/lib but still i am facing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

In my case there were 2 jars-
 mail.jar and geronimo-javamail_1.4_mail-1.8.4.jar.

Only after removing both from my app's lib and putting mail.jar in server's lib , error was resolved.

If you are not sure what other jars could have this javax.mail.Session class present , you can use below command to find.

**`forfiles /S /M *.jar /C "cmd /c jar -tvf @file | findstr /C:"Session" && echo @path"`**

Session refers to class **Session** we are searching